# How to redirect from http to https with a redirect on IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

I would like all traffic to my site to use https on IIS.

How do I configure a redirect to do that?

(Note: this will be self answered, as there is no correct answer anywhere on this.)

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx) link supposedly answers this question:

However, no-one so far as been able to get it the answer to work, as you end up with an endless loop of a redirect redirecting to a redirect.

So after working with this and resolving it, here is the correct answer:

1. Install the Http Redirect Feature if it is not already installed.
2. Create two sites, not one site.  The first site is the insecure site which is bound to http only.  Do not bind https on this site.
3. The second site is your secure site.  This is bound to https and your security cert.
4. On the insecure site, add the http redirect: "Redirect requests to this destination: https://example.com"   Select status code of Permanent (301).
5. Test.  Any request to http://example.com will be forwarded to https://example.com.